# Is it possible to pull a link preview when posting to Google+ via SMS?

Tags: google-plus, sms

I have my Google+ account set up so I can post via SMS. When I post a URL, the preview of the link (and image) is not displayed.

Google seems to fall short in documenting their own products, at times... and at other times simply doesn't make features known publicly.

How to use Google+ SMS - http://support.google.com/plus/answer/1304920

Nothing is listed in the documentation, but does anyone know if there is a "shortcode" that needs to be used to pull the preview?